# Tracing where a variable is defined

Tags: php, global-variables

I am working with someone else's php code and coming upon a global variable called **$options** which contains an array that I need to modify.

The site is coded across a large number of files and **$options** being of a global scope prevents me from tracing it back to where it is defined or initialized.

Is there some tool or function that will point to the path or file where **$options** is defined?

Comment: Many text editors, like EditPlus (and that's an old one), have a Search in Files feature.  That's one idea.  If you are using a Linux box, use GREP.

Comment: Consider using and IDE such as Eclipse and manage your whole project inside it. The IDE will trace class, methods and global definitions for you.

Comment: If your using windows you can use Powershell's [Select-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849903.aspx) as a replacement for grep

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with global variables is always a pain. 
If you hosted the files on a Linux server, go to the root directory and perform the search

```
grep -rn 'global $options' .
```

It will list all the files where $options is used. Cheers!